# handling relationship ids with afincrementalstore

Tags: core-data, afincrementalstore

In my data model, I have the below entities:

```
Album:
    - name (required attribute)
    - year
    - tracks 
    ...

Track:
   - name (required attribute)
   - Album
    ...
```

I have a server data response that includes relationship details by providing just the identifiers of the related objects.

/Albums/1
returns:

```
{
   id:2,
   name:"The White Album",
   year:1968,
   ...
   tracks: ({id:12}, {id:13}, {id:14})
}
```

As it stands, AFIncrementalStore can't save the context because the track entity objects are failing validation.  Is there any way to address this besides making the relationship optional in the data model?

Answer (score 0):

I think if we think to your own model as follows:

- Album have many tracks
- one track has Album

from this information we need a relationship between two Entities (one-To_many) .. 
you can fetch request with tracks and in method `- (NSDictionary *)attributesForRepresentation:(NSDictionary *)representation ofEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity fromResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response` you can check for entity name and mapping data to your model ..

as I know if your model name is like response key from server, AFIncremantalStore will do mapping automatically based on keys on your model and response from server ..

thats all I understand from your question and I hope the answer is satisfy to your question ..